# Comparing large (~40GB) of textual data using Pandas or an alternative approach

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large body of csv data, around 40GB of size that I need to process (lets call it the 'body'). The data in each file in this body consists of single column CSV files. Each row is a keyword consisting of words and short sentences, e.g.

```
Dog
Feeding cat
used cars in Brighton
trips to London
.....
```

This data needs to be compared against another set of files (this one 7GB in size, which I will call 'Removals'), any keywords from the Removals need to be identified and removed from the body. The data for the Removals is similar to whats in the body, i.e:

```
Guns
pricless ming vases
trips to London
pasta recipes
........
```

While I have an approach that will get the job done, it is a very slow approach and could take a good week to finish. It is a multi-threaded approach in which every file from the 7GB body is compared in a for loop against files from the body. It casts the column from the Removals file as a list and then filters the body file to keep any row that is not in that list. The filtered data is then appended to an output file:

```
def thread_worker(file_):


    removal_path="removal_files"
    allFiles_removals = glob.glob(removal_path + "/*.csv", recursive=True)
    print(allFiles_removals)

    print(file_)
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_)

    file_df.columns = ['Keyword']

    for removal_file_ in allFiles_removals:

        print(removal_file_)
        vertical_df = pd.read_csv(vertical_file_, header=None)

        vertical_df.columns = ['Keyword']

        vertical_keyword_list = vertical_df['Keyword'].values.tolist()

        file_df = file_df[~file_df['Keyword'].isin(vertical_keyword_list)]


    file_df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

Obviously, my main aim is to work out how to get this done faster.Is Pandas even the best way to do this? I tend to default to using it when dealing with CSV files.

Comment: What do you want to compare? All data in one file against all data in another one?

Comment: It would be more accurate to say I want to take one group of files (totalling 40GB) and I want to remove any keywords that also appear in another group of files (the 7GB body).

Comment: I would split the body into chunks, of say 1GB each and maybe do the rest in parallel on each of the chunks depending on your RAM size. Then convert a chunk (using `awk`) so it has one word per line and introduce a NUL and another unique character to mark starts and ends of lines. Then run a `grep -vfb` of the removals against the chunk. Then reassemble.

Comment: Its a good idea, but some of the terms I need removed are multiple words for example if 'trips to London' were in the 7GB body then it would need to be identified and removed from the 40GB body.

Comment: @GreenGodot, could you post a sample of `Removal` data set?

Comment: Any chance you'd be able to fit `Removal` into memory as a `set`?

Comment: @GreenGodot, how do you want to remove words from the "body"? Do you want to remove single words or complete rows? What about different cases (upper, lower) - do you want to have exact match or case-insensitive?

Comment: This is not a [MCVE] (yet).

Comment: Maybe SFrame will be able to help
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SFrame

Comment: @MaxU, I want complete rows removed from the body. Case sensitivity is also important, it needs to be an exact match. In the example of Removal I just added in as an edit, "trips to London" will have to be removed from the "body" as it is present in the "Removals" data.

Comment: Fine, instead of the `grep` I suggested earlier, just use `awk`.

Comment: Can you change dataset? Sort it, i.e.? Or save position, sort and restore position? I just want to raise point that then we are talking about 40GB of words - it's mainly about efficiency of algorithm - not comparison panda vs pure cvs.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
# read up "removal"  keywords from all CSV files, get rid of duplicates
removals = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='~', header=None, names=['Keyword']) for f in removal_files]
                     ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()


df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in body_files:
    # collect all filtered "body" data (file-by-file)
    df = pd.concat([df,
                    pd.read_csv(f, sep='~', header=None, names=['Keyword']) \
                      .query('Keyword not in @removals.Keyword')],
                   ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Its a good approach but the downside would be running out of memory when loading all of the files into it...

Comment: @GreenGodot, what constraints do you have? How much RAM is available for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably read them in small chunks and make the text column as category to drop duplicates while reading

from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

TextFileReader = pd.read_csv(path, chunksize=1000, dtype = {"text_column":CategoricalDtype})  # the number of rows per chunk

dfList = []
for df in TextFileReader:
dfList.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfList,sort=False)